# Replacing spring as backend in jhipster

Tags: playframework, jhipster

I have been playing with jhipster and I would like to know if there has been any attempt to replace spring with other frameworks, I am thinking of Play actually.
Any estimate on how hard it could be?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are blueprints for other frameworks, including Micronaut, Quarkus, NestJS, and .NET Core. This proves it's possible, but it doesn't mean it'll be easy.

https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/official-blueprints/

Creating it is one thing. Maintaining it and keeping it up to date is a whole other challenge, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are totally right.